# howto extract data from upcdatabase request

Tags: node.js, http

in my project I have to do a request to upcDatabase.com, I amworking with nodeJS, I get the answer from the server but I do not  how to extractthe data this are the important part of my code:

```
module.exports = function (http,upc){    
var upc_ApiKey  = "XXX",
url = "http://upcdatabase.org/api/json/"+upc_ApiKey+'/'+upc;
http.get(url,function(resp){
// my code to read the response
```

I do not get any error, but the resp is a big Json and I do not know where to find the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you using the [`superagent`](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent) module. It provides much more functionality than the built-in `http` request and it will automatically parse the response for you.

```
request
    .get(url)
    .end(function(err, res) {
        if (res.ok) {
            // Her ethe res object will be already parsed. For example if
            // the server returns Content-Type: application/json
            // res will be a javascript object that you can query for the properties
            console.log(res);
        } else {
            // oops, some error occurred with the request
            // you can check the err parameter or the res.text
        }
    });
```

You could achieve the same with the built-in http module but with much more code:

```
var opts = url.parse(url);
opts.method = "GET";
var req = http.request(opts, function (res) {
    var result = "";

    res.setEncoding("utf8");
    res.on("data", function (data) {
        result += data;
    });
    if (res.statusCode === 200) {
        res.on("end", function () {
            // Here you could use the result object
            // If it is a JSON object you might need to JSON.parse the string
            // in order to get an easy to use js object
        });
    } else {
        // The server didn't return 200 status code
    }
});

req.on("error", function (err) {
    // Some serious error occurred during the request
});

// This will send the actual request
req.end();
```